# How to find the area through the given integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

If $\int \int _Ax\:dxdy\:$, I want to find the area between the parabola $y=x^2$ and the straight line $2x-y+8=0$. I know that the equation of the straight line is $y=2x+8$, so after sketching the graph i found the two points of intersection are $\left(-2,4\right)$ and $\left(4,16\right)$, thus to find the area between the two curves is

> $A=\int _{-2}^4\left(-x^2+2x+8\right)\:dx=36$

i know this yields the right answer. But how do i find the same answer using the given integral from the question, which is $\int \int _Ax\:dxdy\:$? thank you so much for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

$$
{\rm area} \ (A) = \int_A 1\ dS=\int_{-2}^4\int_{x^2}^{2x+8} 1\ dydx=\int_{-2}^4
 y|_{x^2}^{2x+8}\ dx $$

Comment: You should discourage use of $A$ as a real number and a set simultaneously. Use $\mathrm{Vol}(A)$ instead.

Comment: I see. I will fix it.

Comment: I once did it in my calculation but i'm not sure why i have to put x equals to 1? @HeeKwonLee

Comment: Here $1$ means weight density. If density is 1 then weight and area of slate $A$ are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Double integral means that $\mathscr D(f(x)) \subseteq \mathbb R^2$. So this integral would mean volume of a shape limited by $f(x)$, where $x \in \mathbb R^2$.
You should use simple Riemann integral, as $f(x) : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, so $\mathscr D(f(x)) \subseteq \mathbb R$ and $x$ has the only component.